# Is there any way to store the elements present in the file to the to the array of the object in java

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

The program is giving correct output when `System.out.println(mem[i].memName);` but the array of class "member" is giving output (alex alex alex alex) i.e of the last line of the file (mentioned at the END of the CODE) 
it should give all the names listed in the file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class member//CLASS TO BE USED AS ARRAY TO STORE THE PRE REGISTERED MEMBERS FED INSIDE 
{                    //THE FILE "member.txt"

    static int memId;
    static String memName, memEmail, memPh, date;
}

public class entry// file name
{

    static DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
    static LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static member[] mem = new member[100];
    static trainer[] tr = new trainer[100];
    static FileWriter fwriter = null;
    static BufferedWriter bwriter = null;
    static FileReader fread = null;
    static BufferedReader bread = null;

    static void memberEntry() {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("NEW MEMBER IS BEING ADDED");

        try {
            fwriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\itisa\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\GYM
                       PROJECT\\member.txt
            ",true);
                     bwriter = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);

            System.out.println("Member ID is being automatically genrated");
            int autoID = 101 + getMemberRecords();//Fetching the number of members so that ID can 
            //Be genrated automatically
            i = autoID % 100;//jumping toward the next loaction location
            System.out.println("Member ID of new member is" + autoID);
            mem[i].memId = autoID;

            System.out.print("Enter the name of the member:");
            mem[i].memName = input.next();

            System.out.print("Enter the email address of memeber:");
            mem[i].memEmail = input.next();

            System.out.print("Enter the contact number of memeber:");
            mem[i].memPh = input.next();

            System.out.println("Date has been feeded automatically:" + dtf.format(now));
            mem[i].date = dtf.format(now);

            bwriter.write(String.valueOf(mem[i].memId));
            bwriter.write("|");
            bwriter.write(mem[i].memName);
            bwriter.write("|");
            bwriter.write(mem[i].memEmail);
            bwriter.write("|");
            bwriter.write(mem[i].memPh);
            bwriter.write("|");
            bwriter.write(mem[i].date);
            bwriter.write("\n");

            System.out.println("MEMBER CREATED SUCCESSFULLY");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

            bwriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }

    static int getMemberRecords() {
        int count = 0, i = 0;

        try {
            fread = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\itisa\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\GYM PROJECT\\member.txt");
            bread = new BufferedReader(fread);

            String lineRead = null;
            while ((lineRead = bread.readLine()) != null)//Just to get to know the number of member 
            //alreadyinside the file
            {
                String[] t = lineRead.split("\\|");
                mem[i].memId = Integer.parseInt(t[0]);
                mem[i].memName = t[1];
                mem[i].memEmail = t[2];
                mem[i].memPh = t[3];
                mem[i].date = t[4];
                i++;
                count++;

            }
            System.out.println(mem[0].memName);//should print the 1st name present in the name 
            //i.e, RAVI 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Total number of accounts:" + getMemberRecords());

    }
}
```

Elements stored in the file:

```
101|RAVI|itisadi23@gmai.com|9102019656|2020/04/30
102|aditya|adi@gmail.com|9386977983|2020/04/30
103|anurag|anu@ymail.com|10000000000|2020/04/30
104|alex|alex123@mail.com|2829578303|2020/04/30
```

Expected output:

```
RAVI 
Total number of accounts = 4
```

My output:

```
alex
Total number of accounts=4
```

In Short it is giving last name as output no matter what index number is given to fetch the data.

Comment: trainer class ..please provide

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting somewhat but you should spend some time to improve the quality of your questions so it becomes more readable and please stop screaming, it is just rude.

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger?

Comment: I agree with @JoakimDanielson, I added to it, it isn't a bad formulated question but the formatting made it almost unreadable. You should spend 2 minutes reading the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  section of the site.

Comment: The described symptoms would be indicative of initializing all the members of `mem` to the same object (e.g., `member m = new member(); for (int i=0;i < mem.length; ++i) { mem[i] = m; }`).   But I'm not seeing any code that initializes any member of `mem` to anything at all, so I'm surprised it's not an immediate `NullPointerException` the first time `mem[i]` is accessed.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, it's there, line 10ish `static member[] mem = new member[100];`

Comment: Sorry for the trouble GUYS but im actually asking any question  for the first time on stack overflow...

Comment: No, that just initializes `mem` itself; the individual members `mem[0]`, `mem[1]`, ..., `.mem[99]` are all initially `null` until something else sets them to reference actual `member` objects.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, I've been doing C++, I forgot about that, my appologies. It doesn't throw because these are static members.

Comment: `static` or not, null references are still null references...  If you're not getting NPE, then those `mem` elements must have gotten assigned real references _somehow_.  Is it possible you've shared outdated code?

Comment: @KevinAnderson, when a class has static members you don't need to initialize it, you', efectively `mem[i].memName` amounts to `member.memName`, see https://onlinegdb.com/HkTWZiYYI running fine, then remove the static qualifiers from `member`class members and you'll see the exception thrown.

Comment: @anastaciu Yep, you're right; I didn't catch on soon enough that all the members of `member` are `static`.  An old lesson learned so long ago that was good to learn again...

Comment: Thankyou @anastaciu for showing your efforts towards my project!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `member` class members must not be `static`, if they are, they're shared by every `member` class object.

The other problem is that your `member` array nodes are not being initialized, you'll need:

[**Live demo**](https://onlinegdb.com/BkvBgjFt8)

```
class member
{                   
    int memId; //non-static
    String memName, memEmail, memPh, date; //non-static
}
```

and

```
//...
while ((lineRead = bread.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] t = lineRead.split("\\|");
    mem[i] = new member(); // initialize every node
    mem[i].memId = Integer.parseInt(t[0]);
    mem[i].memName = t[1];
    mem[i].memEmail = t[2];
    mem[i].memPh = t[3];
    mem[i].date = t[4];
    i++;
    count++;
}
System.out.println(mem[0].memName);
//...
```

Output:

```
RAVI
```

Note that you can use [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or other java collection.